# Fullcalender slotLabelFormat

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm trying to format slot label for each hour, so it would display like so:

```
9:00am
15
30
45
10:00am
15
30
45
11:00am
```

Here is my config:

```
    slotLabelInterval="00:15:00"
    slotLabelFormat={{
         minute: '2-digit',
         omitZeroMinute: true,
         meridiem: 'short'
        }}
   defaultTimedEventDuration="00:15:00"
```

However, hours are showing a full date, instead of an hour value.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: AFAIK you can't vary the slot format. Each slot will get the same format.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using FullCalendar 4.2.0 (SmartAdmin bundle).

Try this:

```
slotDuration: '00:15:00',
slotLabelInterval: '00:15:00',
slotLabelFormat: function (date)
{
    if (date.date.minute == 0)
        return date.date.hour.toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':00';

    return date.date.minute;
},
```

I did not however find any option to put html in the label format to create a bold version of the hour. I checked in 4.2.0 & 4.3.1.

Comment: I have actually given up on this one, and your solution worked! thanks very much :D